# Can i regenerate my own session id in servlet?

Tags: session, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java secure session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163319/java-secure-session)

I know once you run yor jsf application the server will generate a session id, But how can i do like once the user login to the system then regenerate the session id ? Can i do this?