# Preventing session fixation in java

Tags: java, session-fixation

I have a web application written in java. We don't use sessions in authentication process. An application scan was ran and it was found that we have possibility of session fixation attack. I am wondering when we are not using session, how do you fix or prevent session fixation?  This is what the FORTIFY scan report tells

```
The following changes were applied to the original request:
• Added parameter 'Cookie_abcxyz.com-443' with the following value 'R3777273810'
• Removed cookie 'Cookie_abcxyz.com-443'

Request/Response:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 43
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Win32)
Host: myportal.abcxyz.com
Cookie_abcxyz.com-443=R3777273810
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: Cookie_abcxyz.com-443=R3777273810; path=/
Content-Length: 11211
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2012 17:08:14 GMT
Server: abcxyz
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> We don't use sessions in authentication process.... I am wondering
>   when we are not using session

This is irrelevant. I assume that you use session management for your server.This error report indicates that you don't validate the query string for your session identifiers.
Check here for some examples of how you can be attacked: [Session Fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation)

**UPDATE:**
I suspected that you didn't use a standard container.I can't tell you what you actually should do since you have not put any code, but from your description and the fact that you got a report for such a finding the problem is that you allow URL re-rewriting and the attacker can use it to "steal" the session by passing in a known session id.
Broadly speaking what you should do is after the user has logged in then invalidate the current session and create a new one on the spot.As a result the already "stoled" id can not be reused.

And since the information you provide in the post is so little you should take some time to study some of the following to identify the part of your code that is in problem:
[OWASP 1](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Fixation_in_Java)
[OWASP 2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Fixation)
[OWASP 3](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Fixation_Protection)
[Java Secure session SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163319/java-secure-session)
[ASP as well](http://alexsmolen.com/blog/?p=17)
[Interesting paper on session fixation](http://www.acros.si/papers/session_fixation.pdf)
[Some HTTP utilities from OWASP that you could perhaps use](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultHTTPUtilities.java)
[Session fixation in Java](https://blog.whitehatsec.com/tag/session-fixation/)
[Secure Session Management](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/news/1156684/OWASP-Guide-to-Building-Secure-Web-Applications-and-Web-Services-Chapter-11-Session-Management)

Comment: How do I know I use session management ? How can I validate the query string for session identifiers?

Comment: @yogsma:I don't know that you use it.I assume that you do since it is impossible to build any useful web application without keeping state.It depends on how you do session management.Do you use URL re-writing or cookies?

Comment: @yogsma:.Also you don't mention which container you use.Is it Tomcat?You should read the link I gave you

Comment: We don't use container. We have a custom written webserver.

Comment: @yogsma:Dah...I suspected that but how were we supposed to know this???You should provide such critical details if you actually want to get help

Comment: @yogsma: custom webservers are a very high risk.  You should consider a known container and use the session management from that.

Comment: @yogsma:I updated with some more interesting links.You should study them.You could also put some code to see what you are doing

Comment: @user384706 - What do you suggest for cookies?

Comment: @yogsma:You are doing your own session management eh?The main idea is that you invalidate the session id after the user is authenticated and create a new one.

Comment: @user384706 - How do you know we are doing session management? Since the web server has been written by other developers, there are no methods which will give me session id or any information related to session.